# Specify special JsonConverter for type without adding it to WebApi serialization settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Given abstract class

```
public abstract class A 
{

}
```

with two classes B and C that implements abstract stuff in class A and a JsonConverter that can read json into either B or C.

How do i link the JsonConverter to the type A such it can be used in WebApi 2 Controller as model

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(A model)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want your converter to just apply to WebApi model binding, then you should be able to add your converter to the global formatter:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new AConverter());
```

If you want your converter to always be applied by Json.NET, consider the `JsonConverterAttribute`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(AConverter))]
class A
{
   ...
}
```